# A conceptual doubt in limits

Tags: limits

Why isn't $1^{\infty}$ considered as equal to $1$ but is said to be an indeterminate form in limits?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will clear your major doubt.

> $(a)^{b} =1 $ when $a=1$ and $b \to \infty$

But ,

$(a)^{b} $ when $a \to 1$ and $b \to \infty$ can  attain any (positive) value.

(By $\to 1$  , I mean a real number that tends closer and closer to $a$ but $\neq 1$.)

Comment: I don't understand this notation

Comment: @StellaBiderman I hope my edit clears what I mean ro say.

Comment: But still.. the question isn't really asking what happens when a tends to 1.

Comment: So you understand what it's asking? I don't, and I won't waste time on it.